# Accessing different elements in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have names in an ignore list file called Ignore.json

```
[
"George",
"Carl"
]
```

The file is called ignore.json

In my program I am reading the file into the ignore variable

```
var ignore;

ignore = require("./Ignore.json");
```

Now I want to see if my array element is not in that list then if it is not in that list output the code.

I know how to check if an element is in an array like:

```
for (list in lists) {

        if(lists[list].to.toLowerCase() in ignore){
```

But if I want to check that it is not "in" the list, what is the opposite of in in javascript?

Comment: It's not correct to use the `in` operator in this situation. `in` checks whether an object has a certain property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list, i;
for(i=0;i<lists.length;i++){
    list = lists[i];
    if(ignore.indexOf(lists[list].to.toLowerCase()) === -1){
        // -1 indicates item was not in list
    }
}
```

Comment: then do i need to nest an if statement within this as if(-1) then continue?

Comment: @user2811419: No. The condition of the `if` statement evaluates to `true` if the element is not in the array.