# How would I change the logic of this if statement to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I want to check if an array element is contained within another array, so far I have tried these two ways and they both just execute true even if the ignoreList contains the element.

```
for (email in emailList) {

        if(!(emailList[email].to.toLowerCase() in ignoreList)){
        //if(ignoreList.indexOf(emailList[email].to.toLowerCase()) == -1){
```

I tried both the commented and uncommented way.

From a high level point of view. I want to check if the email in the emailList is contained in the ignoreList, if it is in the ignoreList then I do no want it to execute.

Comment: Typically using `for...in` for arrays is bad practice. It's better used for object iteration. Try using a normal for loop

Comment: `to.toLowerCase()` should be `toLowerCase()` unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Post your entire code

Comment: I think that's the `to` property of the email.

Comment: [This is very similar to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355729/accessing-different-elements-in-a-javascript-array). What's the issue that that answer didn't solve?

Comment: ... @Andy wow. The OP even checked the answer with a `for` loop and he still went with a `for ... in`?

Comment: Hint: Check if emailList[email].to.toLowerCase() really contains what you expect. I had a similar peoblem with multidimensional objects not working in for..in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<emailList.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<ignoreList.length;j++) {
        if (emailList[i].toLowerCase() != ignoreList[j]) //or whatever logic you're trying to pull off here
    }
}
```

This will iterate BOTH arrays, checking every possible combination of email to ignores, and you can use an easier if statement this way

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < emailList.length; i++){ 
    if (ignoreList.indexOf(emailList[i].toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        // Your code to deal with the ignored email here
}
```

Older browsers don't have indexOf for arrays, so you might need to add this prototype:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Why would you return true? Surely the OP wants to process all emails, and not just stop when the first ignore is found

Comment: That's just to indicate that the email is in the ignore list. I don't know if he wants to use this code in a function or just deal with the email in question right there. He can simply remove the return and insert his code in place

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `in` in your `if` clause. See for example [MDN docs for `in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> Syntax: prop in objectName
>
> prop
>       A string or numeric expression representing a property name or
>   array index.

and you are trying to check `some@example.com` within `['some@example.com', 'some1@example.com']` wich is always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Underscore.js this is pretty straightforward without all the gotchas of `in` or the boilerplate of `for`:

```
_.each( emailList, function( email ) {
  if ( !_.contains( ignoreList, email ) ) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Even nicer if you can change your data so the format of `emailList` is the same as `ignoreList` (a simple array of email address strings):

```
_.each( _.difference( emailList, ignoreList ), function( email ) {
  // ...
});
```